# Why was the Dependencies section removed from the Shared code of a UWP App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, skiasharp

I built a test UWP App using build 15.6.2 of Visual Studio 2017.  The UWP project was built by choosing: "Cross Platform" -> "Mobile App (Xamarin Forms)", and then I Chose: "Blank App".

The Solution window looked like:

[image]

Notice the **Dependencies** section in the Shared code section.

Then I created a similar project with Visual Studio, build 15.6.4, and I got a Solution window like:

[image]

Notice that the **Dependencies** section has been removed.
My code to test SkiaSharp is broken because the MainPage.xaml cannot find SkiaSharp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="TrinMeter.MainPage">

  <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasView"
                     PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />

</ContentPage>
```

Why has Microsoft removed the Dependencies section?

Charles

Comment: Your answer is not helpful.  Either you are not using build 15.6.4, or you are, and you are not using SkiaSharp.  Using the template shown in the “bottom one”, you will see that the screen is a rendering of the XML in MainPage,xml of the shared code.  Actually, you will see that the template includes an XML label that produces the text "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the projects are different.  The top one uses a PCL or Standard Library for sharing code.  The bottom one uses a shared library.   To add a reference or nuget package you need to add it to the UWP, iOS, and UWP app.

Comment: The point I’m making is that you cannot replace the XML label with SkiaSharp graphics text that says: “Welcome to SkiaSharp”.  By telling me to abandon the shared code and duplicate the SkiaSharp code in the three device modules (UWP, iOS and Droid), you are then going to get in trouble with Microsoft marketing.  They are telling developers that shared code is the preferred way to do development.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several templates, I finally discovered the correct template.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2: This is very important.  Note that the radio button has been changed to ".NET Standard".

[image]

Step 3: Now that we can add dependencies, add SkiaSharp

[image]

and

[image]

The MainPage.xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test2"
             x:Class="Test2.MainPage">

  <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasView"
                     PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />

</ContentPage>
```

and the code-behind is:

```
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test2 {
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
    public static readonly SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
    public MainPage() {
      InitializeComponent();
      canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
      Content = canvasView;
    }

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e) {
      var surface = e.Surface;
      var canvas = surface.Canvas;
      var width = e.Info.Width;
      var height = e.Info.Height;
      var x = width/2.0f;
      var y = height/2.0f;
      var paint = new SKPaint();
      paint.TextSize = 14.0f;
      paint.IsAntialias = true;
      paint.Color = SKColors.Red;
      paint.IsStroke = false;
      var textBounds = new SKRect();
      var text = "Welcome to SkiaSharp";
      paint.MeasureText(text, ref textBounds);
      var textWidth = textBounds.Width + 4.0f;
      var textHeight = textBounds.Height + 2.0f;
      x -= textWidth/2.0f;

      canvas.DrawText(text, x, y, paint);
    }
  }
}
```

When select the Test2.UWP to be the start-up project, you will then see:

[image]

Now it's time for a beer!